# Find all documents in MongoDB by field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having trouble finding all documents by field value. Basically I want to find all documents by field companyurl. I then want to parse this into csv reader and only print the company url fields value into a csv document. Currently my code prints all fields of the mongoDB document.

Ultimately I would the print to CSV being only the companyurl fields value. Is there a way in find to selectively query based of all document fields?

My document looks like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('63462fd9e52e05829198d5a2')
company:"google"
companyurl:"facebook.com"
__v:0

_id: ObjectId('63462fd9e52e05829198d5a2')
company:"google"
companyurl:"amazon.com"
__v:0

_id: ObjectId('63462fd9e52e05829198d5a2')
company:"google"
companyurl:"stackoverflow.com"
__v:0

_id: ObjectId('63462fd9e52e05829198d5a2')
company:"google"
companyurl:"instagram.com"
__v:0
```

Code:

```
mongodb.connect(
 url,
 { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  (err, client) => {
   if (err) throw err;

client
  .db("mernapp")
  .collection("scrapeds")
  .find({})
  .toArray((err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(data);
    const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ header: true });
    const csvData = json2csvParser.parse(data);

    fs.writeFile("bezkoder_mongodb_fs.csv", csvData, function(error) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log("Write to bezkoder_mongodb_fs.csv successfully!");
    });

    client.close();
  });
 }
);
```

Comment: Does this work for you - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/project/

Answer (score 0):

Received an answer and this worked for me.

```
const projection = { _id: 0, companyurl: 1 };

 mongodb.connect(
 url,
 { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
 (err, client) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  client
  .db("mernapp")
  .collection("scrapeds")
  .find().project(projection)
  .toArray((err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(data);
    const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ header: true });
    const csvData = json2csvParser.parse(data);

    fs.writeFile("bezkoder_mongodb_fs.csv", csvData, function(error) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log("Write to bezkoder_mongodb_fs.csv successfully!");
    });

    client.close();
  });
  }
  );
```